# Git - Bare Repository is not up to date

Tags: git, repository, updates, git-bare

ok I try again to describe my problem.
At first let me say I am a beginner in Git. I have read a lot of stuff but there some points that are not clear for me.

I work local on a workingcopy. My head on local branchx have the same id as remote branchx on gitlab. But on the gitlabserver I can see two branches 1. bare/branchx 2. branchx.
And when I compare this two branches the `bare/branchx` is behind the `branchx`.

I searched for a while to find the command to update `bare/branchx` to `branchx` but didn't find.
I have the suspicion that something is going wrong.

Another questions is, why do I see this two branches instead of one - the `bare/branchx`.
As I've read, on remote server have to be only an bare repository. But when I pull my Data to the remote, there isn't a non bare repo? Where are my data else, when the Bare repo didn't have a workingtree?

So many questions, so many answers and ways to do things on git. I am confused

@kan when I type

```
 git branch -a
```

i get

```
master
* x2
remotes/origin/bare/master
remotes/origin/bare/x2
remotes/origin/bare/x3
remotes/origin/bare/x4
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/x2
remotes/origin/x3
remotes/origin/x4
```

so i have a bare master and master.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is unclear. Could you improve it?

Comment: Please provide the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all` for both repositories, at least for the top relevant commits. Or as @kan said improve your question :)

Comment: I don't understand what does `bare` mean in your case. To update remote branch you could push to it. There is no such thing `pull to`, you could only pull from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I pull my Data to the remote, there isn't a non bare repo? Where are my data else, when the Bare repo didn't have a workingtree?

You don't pull to the remote, you are *pushing* to the remote.
And you are always pushing to a **[*bare* repo](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/bare.html)** (to avoid any difference between the index in the `.git` directory, and the working tree itself -- all the checked out files: no working tree, no problem)

You should only see `remotes/origin/master`: this is the branch that should be at the same level as `master` once you have push `master` to `origin`.

`remotes/origin/bare/master` shouldn't exist, and "bare" here can be a branch namespace

Comment: Yes I mean **pushing to remote** . And ... holy thank you so much. I thought this     remotes/origin/bare/master is the barerepo. So I delete it. Thanks to all others for spending time on this.